# Filtering Sentry Laravel events before send

Tags: php, laravel, sentry

Currently using Sentry for Laravel and really liking it but I would like to filter events sent to Sentry via client side using the [before_send](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/configuration/filtering/#using-beforesend) or any other options to filter/rate limit to try and cut back on duplicate events being sent. I have been hit a few times with events that rapidly stack up and leave a big hit on our event quota. I do not have the business plan so do not have the option to rate limit on the Sentry server side. Any options to drop events after a set number of the same event have been sent or limit the total amount of events that can be sent in 24 hours?

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at [spike protection](https://docs.sentry.io/product/accounts/quotas/#spike-protection)? This maybe helps a bit. Other than that there is not much you can do unless you are able to track which events were sent previously, since PHP is stateless this is not implemented in the SDK but in theory you could write it yourself and count occurrences and prevent sending x amount in a certain time window. Another option is [sampling](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/configuration/sampling/#sampling-error-events).

Comment: @AlexBouma Thanks for your response. I have seen the spike protection and it is enabled. While I like the sampling, Sentry has been so good on catching small edge case issues that we were able to fix and I fear not getting those reliably with sampling on.

Answer (score 0):

This came up while I was searching for a very similar answer, since I didn't find one either I spent some time coming up with a solution myself. I've documented it all at https://stevenwoodson.com/blog/conserving-sentry-transactions-by-ignoring-laravel-routes/

It comes down to adding the following to `/config/sentry.php`

```php
'before_send_transaction' => function (
    \Sentry\Event $transaction
): ?\Sentry\Event {
    $ignore = ['_debugbar', 'monitoring', 'pleaseignoreme'];
    $request = $transaction->getRequest();
    $check = array_filter($ignore, function ($url) use ($request) {
        if (stripos($request['url'], $url) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    if (count($check) > 0) {
        return null;
    }

    return $transaction;
},
```